# Property not Overridden when using by keyword in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm attempting to have two implementations of an interface one of which inherits the default values from the other implementation, but overrides one.

Here's an example that shows the behavior:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println(Bottom.value) // prints: bottom
    println(Bottom.determineValue()) // prints: middle
}

interface Top {

    val value: String

    val otherValue: String

    fun determineValue() = value
}

object Middle : Top {
    override val value = "middle"
    override val otherValue = "something else"
}

object Bottom : Top by Middle {
    override val value = "bottom"
}
```

I'm getting unexpected behavior in that, when the property `value` is used in outside of the `Bottom` implementation, it returns the value from `Middle` instead of `Bottom`.

If someone has more insight on why this is occurring, I'd appreciate any explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior that is described in the [Kotlin documentation of the delegate functionality](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html#overriding-a-member-of-an-interface-implemented-by-delegation).

> Note, however, that members overridden in this way do not get called
> from the members of the delegate object, which can only access its own
> implementations of the interface members

An implementation being used as a delegate has no knowledge that it is being used as a delegate and therefore cannot and will not access members of that other class. Any of its implementations that call its other members will not use the overridden versions that are in the class that are using it as a delegate. There is no way to get around this problem except to re-implement the feature:

```
object Bottom : Top by Middle {
    override val value = "bottom"
    override fun determineValue() = value
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out and linking to that documentation!

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate Tenfour04's answer:

There are two objects here: `Bottom` and `Middle` (both implementing the `Top` interface).

The call path looks like this:

```html
Bottom.determineValue()
           │ (by delegation)
           │
           └──────────→ Middle.determineValue()
                     ┌─────────────┘  (defined in Top)
                     │
                     └→ Middle.value
```

Delegation works by forwarding all (non-overridden) calls to the delegate. Here `Bottom` doesn't override `determineValue()`, so **`Bottom`.`determineValue()` calls its delegate, `Middle`.`determineValue()`, which returns *its own* `value`** (because it knows nothing about `Bottom`).

Comment: I see, I appreciate the further explanation!